# iphone sigkill error

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Hey all
Im working on a game for iphone using cocos2d and sdk 4.1 and I am getting a sigkill error randomly (or what appears to be randomly) while running. Sometimes the error wont appear for hours of trying to simulate it. I have read around on forums and all sigkill problems seem to be when the user tries to close the app, but this is happening during gameplay. Can anyone think of why a sigkill msg is being set off without the user trying to actively close the app.
any advise or tips on trying to track this down would be much appreciated
thanks
g

Comment: How's your memory usage? I know in Linux, at least, `SIGKILL` is sent by the out-of-memory killer when your process is using too much RAM.

Comment: not ram anyway i have available memory being displayed and well in the clear.

Comment: looks like you are right. the available memory being displayed has been lieing to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SIGKILL can be raised for a number of different errors. You should try using the debugger and checking out your stack trace (function calls) to see where the error is happening if you can narrow it down.

Comment: ok the last function called each time seems to be CCSpriteSheet: resizing TextureAtlas capacity from [1] to [2] and then increases from 2 to 4 etc. so maybe is memory issue. is it possible that this capacity becomes too large for the device and that calls the sigkill?

Comment: That's a possibility. I think the phone will shut your app down if it exceeds its memory limit. Maybe you could watch the app with leaks or allocs and see if anything goes haywire? That is about the limit of my iPhone knowledge.